# Cannot overwrite !important style with javascript on desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to rewrite the `display: none !important;`
for `display: block;` with javascript

I'm using this code below, but it has only worked on mobile browsers

```
document.getElementById('billing_state_field').style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");
```

For some reason in Google Chrome and Firefox the style has not changed

This is the page I'm trying to change.
https://vegazcomm.com/finalizar-compra/

(You may need to add an item to the cart and click buy to reach the page)

The idea of ​​the code is to make the address fields appear only after the user touches the Post Code input

To make the fields disappear I had to use `display: none! Important;` on css and overwrite with JS.

The complete code is here

```
<script>


window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('billing_postcode').onclick = function(){
    //console.log('Hello world');
   
document.getElementById('billing_address_1_field').style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");

document.getElementById('billing_address_2_field').style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");

document.getElementById('billing_billing_number_field').style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");

document.getElementById('billing_city_field').style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");

document.getElementById('billing_state_field').style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");
  }
}


</script>
```

Comment: There is insufficient information to solve your problem. Please provide a minimal reproductible esample of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: !important always have higher priority so you will not be able to overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

If inline !important does not work for you as you say, you can hardcode a solution like this:

```js
var e = document.createElement('style');
e.innerHTML = '#billing_state_field {display: block !important;}';

document.body.appendChild(e);
```

```css
#billing_state_field {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="billing_state_field">
  billing_state_field
</div>
```

Comment: You're adding a class to the element, but class selectors is less specific, so the rule from id selector will be applied even if both has an `!important` attribute. You need to change or remove the 'id' first then.

Comment: Edited for better solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the current `!important` rule or add new new css rule with `!important`.

In both cases, you need to access `document.stylesheets`, find the ruleset with `#billing_state_field` selector and then change it.

[More about adding `!important` rules via JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733844/how-to-add-important-to-a-stylesheet-rule-using-javascript)

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList)

As alternative, you can just change the element's `id` like this:

`document.getElementById('billing_state_field').id = ''`

So the rules for `#billing_state_field` will not be applied for it.